# Nuget always takes FallbackFolder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I just created my very first asp.net Core application and added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to it via Nuget.

I took a closer look at the reference and noticed that it points to the FallbackFolder. Now like I said, I'm really not experienced with asp.net core but why does it go to the FallbackFolder and not to the primary one for nuget?

[image: Path of the Reference]

Is that something I should worry about or is it ok if I just leave it how it is because it's not really interfering with anything I do, right now?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fallback folder is a local offline cache for NuGet packages that were provided with the SDK. This being there prevents you from having to download those packages from NuGet directly all the time.

In general, this should not cause problems from you at all. The path being gray (instead of white) also means that this is an implicit value that was automatically resolved. There is no configuration of the dependency that will prevent this from working on other machines, so you don’t need to worry about it.